# ng-animate doesn't let animation be finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I have set animations on `ng-view` to fade for 1 second, but it doesn't let the animation out be finished:

```
.fadethis {
    &.ng-enter, &.ng-leave {
        -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
        -moz-transition: all linear 1s;
        transition: all linear 1s;
        display: block !important;
    }

    &.ng-enter, &.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
      opacity:0;
    }

    &.ng-leave, &.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
      opacity:1;
    }
}
```

can't I make angular-animate finish the 1 second animation first?

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/bnyJ6/79/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not look like your view is actually fading out in your example. If it did, the page you are navigating to would appear and begin fading in before the previous page had finished fading out.

Currently I believe the easiest way to simulate the animations waiting for each other is to add a transition-delay to the enter animation ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2310)).

This can get messy though. In your example the page you are navigating to would still begin to take up space before fading in and bump down the page that is fading out. You can get around this by setting your view to `position: absolute;`.

Demo without `transition-delay`: http://jsfiddle.net/5evFx/

Demo with `transition-delay` and `position: absolute`: http://jsfiddle.net/spKnX/

Working markup:

```
<div ng-view class="view fadein fadeout"></div>
```

Working CSS:

```
.fadein.ng-enter,
.fadeout.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 1s;
    -o-transition: all linear 1s;
    transition: all linear 1s;
    display: block !important;
}

.fadein.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fadeout.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}

.fadein.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    transition-delay: 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}

.fadeout.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}

html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}

.view {
    position: absolute;
}
```